# Javascript: console.log to html

Tags: javascript

I would like to write the console.log output to a div layer.

For example:

```
document.write(console.log(5+1)); //Incorrect, random example
```

Can someone give me a solution to my problem?

Thank you.

EDIT:

what i meant is, for example:

```
console.log("hi");
```

and it shows the output "hi" on the screen.

***Note: An example: http://labs.codecademy.com/#:workspace***

Comment: `console.log` and `document.write` are both side effects, they return nothing.

Comment: So it is impossible to print the output of console.log to the screen?

Comment: What do you mean by the output of the console? The output is `6` right? You can evaluate the expression with `document.write(5+1)`.

Comment: I would like to print console.log's output to the screen

Comment: Thanks to all of you, I was able to explain myself clearly.

Comment: @leonneo: where? I don't see any answer that would capture `console.log`'s output. They all just try to recreate something that looks like that, but they have nothing to do with real `console.log`

Comment: I meant the example given in the question.

Comment: http://labs.codecademy.com/#:workspace

Answer (score 126, accepted):

You can override the default implementation of `console.log()`

```
(function () {
    var old = console.log;
    var logger = document.getElementById('log');
    console.log = function (message) {
        if (typeof message == 'object') {
            logger.innerHTML += (JSON && JSON.stringify ? JSON.stringify(message) : message) + '<br />';
        } else {
            logger.innerHTML += message + '<br />';
        }
    }
})();
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/mGDet/)

Comment: `String(message)` ? Why not just `message`?

Comment: @Nitin's answer is better because it handles objects: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35449256/470749

Comment: In addition to keep using the default console.log functionality as well, add 'old(message);' at the end of the new console.log function.

Comment: Can you show us how to add color to the output from the function above just as you would inside the console.log? Thanks!!!

Comment: Try formatting your stringify like this JSON.stringify(message, undefined, 4) over just the plain JSON.stringify(message) - You'll thank me later

Comment: console.log("name is:",name); ???

Answer (score 37):

Slight improvement on @arun-p-johny answer:

In html,

```
<pre id="log"></pre>
```

In js,

```
(function () {
    var old = console.log;
    var logger = document.getElementById('log');
    console.log = function () {
      for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        if (typeof arguments[i] == 'object') {
            logger.innerHTML += (JSON && JSON.stringify ? JSON.stringify(arguments[i], undefined, 2) : arguments[i]) + '<br />';
        } else {
            logger.innerHTML += arguments[i] + '<br />';
        }
      }
    }
})();
```

Start using:

```
console.log('How', true, new Date());
```

Comment: To keep original `console.log` functionality add `old(...arguments);` at the end of new console log function. Remember to use the spread operator!

Comment: `old.apply(console, arguments);` will also work to keep original arguments.

Comment: I am a bit confused, I'm pretty new to Javascript, what is the structure of this function. the first bracket, why? and what is with the last bracketpair?

Comment: @DaPole it's wrapped in a self-executing anonymous function.

Answer (score 20):

A little late to the party, but I took [@Hristiyan Dodov's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45387558/441662) a bit further still.

*All* console methods are now rewired and in case of overflowing text, an optional [autoscroll to bottom is included](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21067431/441662). Colors are now based on the logging method rather than the arguments.

```js
rewireLoggingToElement(
    () => document.getElementById("log"),
    () => document.getElementById("log-container"), true);

function rewireLoggingToElement(eleLocator, eleOverflowLocator, autoScroll) {
    fixLoggingFunc('log');
    fixLoggingFunc('debug');
    fixLoggingFunc('warn');
    fixLoggingFunc('error');
    fixLoggingFunc('info');

    function fixLoggingFunc(name) {
        console['old' + name] = console[name];
        console[name] = function(...arguments) {
            const output = produceOutput(name, arguments);
            const eleLog = eleLocator();

            if (autoScroll) {
                const eleContainerLog = eleOverflowLocator();
                const isScrolledToBottom = eleContainerLog.scrollHeight - eleContainerLog.clientHeight <= eleContainerLog.scrollTop + 1;
                eleLog.innerHTML += output + "<br>";
                if (isScrolledToBottom) {
                    eleContainerLog.scrollTop = eleContainerLog.scrollHeight - eleContainerLog.clientHeight;
                }
            } else {
                eleLog.innerHTML += output + "<br>";
            }

            console['old' + name].apply(undefined, arguments);
        };
    }

    function produceOutput(name, args) {
        return args.reduce((output, arg) => {
            return output +
                "<span class=\"log-" + (typeof arg) + " log-" + name + "\">" +
                    (typeof arg === "object" && (JSON || {}).stringify ? JSON.stringify(arg) : arg) +
                "</span>&nbsp;";
        }, '');
    }
}


setInterval(() => {
  const method = (['log', 'debug', 'warn', 'error', 'info'][Math.floor(Math.random() * 5)]);
  console[method](method, 'logging something...');
}, 200);
```

```css
#log-container { overflow: auto; height: 150px; }

.log-warn { color: orange }
.log-error { color: red }
.log-info { color: skyblue }
.log-log { color: silver }

.log-warn, .log-error { font-weight: bold; }
```

```html
<div id="log-container">
  <pre id="log"></pre>
</div>
```

Comment: Botteman, it seem that doesn't working on chrome 68 on android!

Comment: now the question is, how can I easily add console.time and console.timeEnd?

Comment: What does this code means?
rewireLoggingToElement(
    () => document.getElementById("log"),
    () => document.getElementById("log-container"), true);

why are you passing arrow function to the function? it's valid javascript but it seems very unfamiliar to me.

Comment: @Gaetano, these are simple closures. Using function variables you can delay executing them until the result is actually needed (for example in case the DOM hasn't initialized yet or will change in the future).

Comment: Nice work. But what about grouping and tabular data? Is there not already some where a web component, or jQuery plugin that "gives you a developer console implemented as a webpage"?

Comment: A little late to the party, but this is the best solution.

Comment: Somehow I can't get ongoing updated content written to the `log-container`. I am running loops within loops with `ajax` calls set to `async: false,` which have many `console.log` calls in them, but the output only gets updated after my loops have finished processing. (I have been having the same problem with my animation, it only plays after my loops finish.) I tried adding a call inside the `ajax` `success: function( result ) {` but could not get it to work. Thanks for your help.

Comment: PS. I just noticed that if I change the window size during the looping process, that I get sporadic writes to the `log-container`. So maybe I would just need to build in some pause for the update to have a chance of catching up with the looping. Not sure how....

Comment: This works great! Thanks! Any suggestions on how to add a cleanup routine to prevent the log grow too big? Right now I just empty that eleLog.innerHTML if its size is more than a predefined value. I thought if I just erase some characters from the beginning, may result an invalid HTML and break the view, something like: eleLog.innerHTML = eleLog.innerHTML.substring(limit / 2);

Answer (score 18):

I come *a bit* late with a more advanced version of [Arun P Johny's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20256785/3130281). His solution doesn't handle multiple `console.log()` arguments and doesn't give an access to the original function.

Here's my version:

```js
(function (logger) {
    console.old = console.log;
    console.log = function () {
        var output = "", arg, i;

        for (i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
            arg = arguments[i];
            output += "<span class=\"log-" + (typeof arg) + "\">";

            if (
                typeof arg === "object" &&
                typeof JSON === "object" &&
                typeof JSON.stringify === "function"
            ) {
                output += JSON.stringify(arg);   
            } else {
                output += arg;   
            }

            output += "</span>&nbsp;";
        }

        logger.innerHTML += output + "<br>";
        console.old.apply(undefined, arguments);
    };
})(document.getElementById("logger"));

// Testing
console.log("Hi!", {a:3, b:6}, 42, true);
console.log("Multiple", "arguments", "here");
console.log(null, undefined);
console.old("Eyy, that's the old and boring one.");
```

```css
body {background: #333;}
.log-boolean,
.log-undefined {color: magenta;}
.log-object,
.log-string {color: orange;}
.log-number {color: cyan;}
```

```html
<pre id="logger"></pre>
```

I took it a *tiny* bit further and added a class to each log so you can color it. It outputs all arguments as seen in the Chrome console. You also have access to the old log via `console.old()`.

Here's a minified version of the script above to paste inline, just for you:

```
<script>
    !function(o){console.old=console.log,console.log=function(){var n,e,t="";for(e=0;e<arguments.length;e++)t+='<span class="log-'+typeof(n=arguments[e])+'">',"object"==typeof n&&"object"==typeof JSON&&"function"==typeof JSON.stringify?t+=JSON.stringify(n):t+=n,t+="</span>&nbsp;";o.innerHTML+=t+"<br>",console.old.apply(void 0,arguments)}}
    (document.body);
</script>
```

Replace `document.body` in the parentheses with whatever element you wish to log into.

Comment: Took this solution a [bit further](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50773729/441662) still. Now inlcudes autoscrolling on overflow and rewires all console methods rather than just `.log()`.

Comment: I know this is an old thread, but I've just started using this in a mobile app. One question: how can I display the file and line that generated the log?

Comment: I don't think you can. You simply don't get that information. If it's an app, you should look for other debugging options like USB debugging.

Comment: take it a tiny bit further and add clear console! ;-)

Answer (score 7):

Create an ouput

```
<div id="output"></div>
```

Write to it using JavaScript

```
var output = document.getElementById("output");
output.innerHTML = "hello world";
```

If you would like it to handle more complex output values, you can use `JSON.stringify`

```
var myObj = {foo: "bar"};
output.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(myObj);
```

Answer (score 2):

This post has helped me a lot, and after a few iterations, this is what we use.

The idea is to post log messages and errors to HTML, for example if you need to debug JS and don't have access to the console.

You do need to change 'console.log' with 'logThis', as it is not recommended to change native functionality.

What you'll get:

- A plain and simple 'logThis' function that will display strings and objects along
  with current date and time for each line
- A dedicated window on top of everything else. (show it only when needed)
- Can be used inside '.catch' to see relevant errors from promises.
- No change of default console.log behavior
- Messages will appear in the console as well.

```js
function logThis(message) {
  // if we pass an Error object, message.stack will have all the details, otherwise give us a string
  if (typeof message === 'object') {
    message = message.stack || objToString(message);
  }

  console.log(message);

  // create the message line with current time
  var today = new Date();
  var date = today.getFullYear() + '-' + (today.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + today.getDate();
  var time = today.getHours() + ':' + today.getMinutes() + ':' + today.getSeconds();
  var dateTime = date + ' ' + time + ' ';

  //insert line
  document.getElementById('logger').insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', dateTime + message + '<br>');
}

function objToString(obj) {
  var str = 'Object: ';
  for (var p in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
      str += p + '::' + obj[p] + ',\n';
    }
  }
  return str;
}

const object1 = {
  a: 'somestring',
  b: 42,
  c: false
};

logThis(object1)
logThis('And all the roads we have to walk are winding, And all the lights that lead us there are blinding')
```

```css
#logWindow {
  overflow: auto;
  position: absolute;
  width: 90%;
  height: 90%;
  top: 5%;
  left: 5%;
  right: 5%;
  bottom: 5%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  z-index: 20;
}
```

```html
<div id="logWindow">
  <pre id="logger"></pre>
</div>
```

Thanks [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5612876/2269874) too, JSON.stringify() didn't work for this.

Answer (score 1):

Copy & paste the code below

```
console.log = (...e) => {for(var i=0;i<e.length;i++){document.getElementById("log").innerHTML += (typeof(e[i]) == "object" ? JSON.stringify(e[i]):e[i]) + "<br />"}};
```

```js
console.log = (...e) => {for(var i=0;i<e.length;i++){document.getElementById("log").innerHTML += (typeof(e[i]) == "object" ? JSON.stringify(e[i]):e[i]) + "<br />"}};

console.log("Hello world",{objectWorks:true},["Array works?","Yes"])
```

```html
<div id="log"></div>
```

If you would like to have the default "console.log", just change the "console.log" to "var CustomNameOfLog". Or Just copy & paste the code below.

```
var CustomNameOfLog = (...e) => {for(var i=0;i<e.length;i++){document.getElementById("log").innerHTML += (typeof(e[i]) == "object" ? JSON.stringify(e[i]):e[i]) + "<br />"}};
```

```js
var customNameOfLog = (...e) => {for(var i=0;i<e.length;i++){document.getElementById("log").innerHTML += (typeof(e[i]) == "object" ? JSON.stringify(e[i]):e[i]) + "<br />"}};

customNameOfLog("Hello world",{objectWorks:true},["Array works?","Yes"])
```

```html
<div id="log"></div>
```