# Print console.log on HTML

Tags: javascript, php, html, console.log

I've a javascript code that is currently working on a shared hosting.

The script gather data from a website and then show it on my website.

Fact is that the data is being showed in the console tab but not on the php page. The script itself contains that code:

```
<script> ... function printFollowers(followersSum) {   console.log(followersSum); // you can do print followersSum wherever you want }

... </script>
```

But I don't understand how to print the "followersSum" function to display it on the HTML.

Does someone can help me?

Comment: If you use the jQuery library.
HTML:
<div id="followers-output"></div>
JS file (instead console.log):
$('#followeers-output').html( followersSum );

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Introduction

Comment: Might want to check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20256760/javascript-console-log-to-html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you have a `<div id="printFollower"></div>` somewhere in your html.

Then do this:

```
function printFollowers(followersSum) {
  document.getElementById('printFollower').innerHTML = followersSum;
  console.log(followersSum); // you can do print followersSum wherever you want
}
```

Using this method, you can control where the list shows up better, apply CSS, etc.

Comment: I got this error:

network.php:17 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null
    at printFollowers (network.php:17)
    at network.php:22

Line 17:   document.getElementById('printFollower').innerHTML = followersSum;
Line 22: printFollowers("followersSum = " + followersSum);

Comment: did you create a `<div>` in your html with an id of printFollowers

Comment: Worked!!! Thank you so much!

Comment: Glad I could help.

Comment: @Andrew The usage of `innerHTML`  is frowned upon as it can be a source of client-side HTML-injection (DOM-XSS). That's why I used `textContent` in my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45132266/2314737).

Answer (score 0):

You can do `document.write()` it will just print it onto the page.

```js
    function printFollowers(followersSum) {
      followersSum = document.getElementById('printFollower').innerHTML
      console.log(followersSum); // you can do print followersSum wherever you want
      document.write(followersSum);
    }

    printFollowers();
```

```html
<div id="printFollower">1</div>
```

Comment: Cannot find a way to make it works.

<script>
function printFollowers(followersSum) {
  followersSum = document.getElementById('printFollower').innerHTML
  console.log(followersSum); // you can do print followersSum wherever you want
  document.write(followersSum);
}
</script>

how I print it? @noah64

Comment: @Andrew if there is an error in the dev console, can you tell it to me?

Comment: If I add printFollowers("5") it'll show 5, obviously.

my code is:

<script>
...
function printFollowers(followersSum) {
  console.log(followersSum); // you can do print followersSum wherever you want
}

...
</script>

Comment: @Andrew have a look at the code now.

Comment: Fact is that the value is update d by the script every X seconds. Your code show me in the browser the value 1.

Comment: @Andrew could you show me your code in a jsfiddle or codepen?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use 'document.write'

```js
function printFollowers(followersSum) {
  document.write(followersSum);
}
printFollowers(prompt("Write some text"));
```

This will print the text straight into the DOM rather than the console. 
For more information on document, [check out the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write)

Answer (score 0):

Change the text content of some element in your document

```js
function printFollowers(followersSum) {
  document.getElementById('myId').textContent = followersSum;
  console.log(followersSum); // you can do print followersSum wherever you want
}

var followersSum = 0;
printFollowers("followersSum = " + followersSum);
```

```html
<div id="myId" />
```