# Getting JS console input and output inside my WINDOW

Tags: javascript, reactjs, console, jsbin

I basically want to do what [jsbin.com](http://www.jsbin.com) does. [Here is their code](https://github.com/jsbin/jsbin/blob/master/public/js/render/console.js). That is having a mostly functional console inside my React application. I managed to hijack the console in such a way that i change the return value of each call via [this](http://tobyho.com/2012/07/27/taking-over-console-log/) guide. But how could i for example show error messages i get in the console in browser?

Is there a way to intercept console method return values and save them to variables?

I would also love to be able to declare variables via my inbrowser console. What would i have to do to make this possible? Can i send input strings to be evaluated by the console?

Edit:

i found a really [great plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jq-console) called jq-console which will handle my input and output, BUT how do i handle the input and output? If i for example want to declare a `var test = 5;`, how would i do this and then return the corresponding console answer?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20256760/javascript-console-log-to-html/20256785

This should help you a lot

Comment: That is a good example thanks. But it still does not give me the return value of the log, does it? e.g. "ReferenceError: x is not defined"