# How to get all console error messages in Angular application

Tags: javascript, angular, console-application

I'm working on a angular application, the problem is when I want to debug it on some smart TVs there is no debug mode and in the background I have some errors that cause application to crash, so, is there any way to get all error messages and print it in a part of the page in my application?

Actually I want to have some kind of virtual console in my own application.

Thank you so much

Comment: What you are trying to convey is called `logging` Search how you can log messages in Angular

Comment: you will need to replace your console logs by a method of your choice located in a service. How to display them in your application is up to you. You may use a fixed floating panel or snackbar messages. I recommend that you use some kind of service to centralize your logs and make them accessible from everywhere in your app.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript: console.log to html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20256760/javascript-console-log-to-html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways to debug it:

- Console.log() - this outputs your message to console. Not sure if you can see it on tv though.
- Create a global error handler, as provided in [Angular documentation](https://angular.io/api/core/ErrorHandler)

If above does not work, you can try to use this solution, which I also found out somewhere on the internet a while ago by using a [snackbar](https://material.angular.io/components/snack-bar/overview) component, which displays errors as a popup:

error.service.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ErrorService {

    checkOnline()
    {
        if (!navigator.onLine) {
            return 'No Internet Connection';
        }
    }

    getClientMessage(error: Error): string {
        return error.message ? error.message : error.toString();
    }

    getClientStack(error: Error): string {
        return error.stack;
    }

    getServerMessage(error: HttpErrorResponse): string {
        var msg = error.error.Message;
        if (!!msg)
            return msg + " : " + error.error.ExceptionMessage;
        return "Application can not execute because API hasn\'t been started";
    }

    getServerStack(error: HttpErrorResponse): string {
        return error.error.StackTrace;
    }
}
```

global-error-handler-component.ts:

```
import { ErrorHandler, Injectable, Injector } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { ErrorService } from './services/error.service';
import { MatSnackBar } from '@angular/material';

@Injectable()
export class GlobalErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler
{
    constructor(private injector: Injector, public snackBar: MatSnackBar) { }

    handleError(error: Error | HttpErrorResponse)
    {
        const errorService = this.injector.get(ErrorService);
        let message;
        let stackTrace = errorService.getClientStack(error);

        if (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse) // Server Error
            message = errorService.getServerMessage(error);
        else // Client Error
            message = errorService.getClientMessage(error);

        this.snackBar.open(message, 'X', { panelClass: ['error'] });
    }
}
```

app.module.ts:

```
import { GlobalErrorHandler } from './global-error-handler.component';
import { MatSnackBarModule } from '@angular/material/snack-bar';
...
  imports: [
...
    MatSnackBarModule,
...
  ],
  providers: [
...
    { provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: GlobalErrorHandler },
...
```

Answer (score 2):

you can override `console.error` method and create smoething like spy

```js
@Injectable({
    providedIn:'root'
})
export class ConsoleSpyService {
  private errorStack :any[] = []
  constructor() { 
    const errMethod = console.error;

    console.error= (...args) => { 
      this.errorStack.push(args);

      errMethod(``,...args)
    }

    Object.freeze(console)
  }


  get errorList() {
    return this.errorStack;//.slice(0);
  }
}
```

you need to inject this class so it created

```js
export class AppModule {

  constructor(c:ConsoleSpyService){}

 }
```

inject the service in component

```
  constructor(private conSpyServ:ConsoleSpyService) {

  }

  get errors(){
    return this.conSpyServ.errorList;
  }
```

template (disply errors list)

```html
<div class="errors" *ngFor="let error of errors">
  {{error.join(' ')}}
</div>
```

> you can display logging to console browser by comment this line `errMethod(``,...args)` in  ConsoleSpyService class

[**demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-z6dezq)

Comment: Actually I want to get system errors not the one I do in console.error, I mean the throw exception from modules

Comment: @malbarmavi can you explain this 'Object.freeze(console)'. What will it do?