# Implement onscreen console log component in Vue.js app

Tags: vue.js

I'm building a Vue.js app that will be run on devices where I don't have access to a dev tools console, such as a game console. I've created a vue DebugPanel component that contains several tabs, one of them being a "log" to write to.

The UI is mostly working as I expect, but now I need to actually take what's in the console and have it output to the element in the component.

I'd like to use [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20256760/javascript-console-log-to-html) of hijacking the consol.log function. This solution works great in a non-vue HTML page, but I'm having trouble with the best way to incorporate it into a Vue.js app.

The issue I'm having is that each tab section on my DebugPanel is hidden/shown based on a v-if attribute. The log element is only in the DOM when its tab element shown. So a call to document.getElementById errors.

Any thoughts on how to implement this in Vue.js?

Answer (score 0):

You can just use Vuex store to pass data through all the app. And i think it would be better to use it in your app for global data.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how you would do this for my scenario? Do you mean, have a `store.state.log` that I'm appending strings on to and then bind that to my log element? These would be strings of HTML and if the app is running for a while, could get rather large. I would be concerned about performance.

Comment: store.state.log, as you said,  but you can dont need to keep html there.
You can keep logs as array and do something like this:
    <div v-for="log in store.state.logs">
        <span :class=" 'log-text-' + log.class">{{ log.text }}</span>
    </div>

Comment: This will allow you to keep logs, control their length and add a highlight for them, based on log.class